Godot 4 3d Gdscript get object collided with
How do I get the name of an object I have collided with or see if I have collided? I want to have an object that changes a variable when touched by the player.
I have set up the group layers and masks but don't know which function to use to see if the object has collided

Rigidbodies and Area CollisionObjects will emit the body_entered signal whenever a body enters (or collides with) them.
You can connect a callable to that.
The signal has the collision node as a parameter, so you can access it's name or whatever properties interest you.
